# Linux kernel wl18xx module_init is it generated?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm looking at this `drivers/net/wireless/ti/wl18xx` driver module.

The traditional `module_init()` is not in the source code. Yet the trace dump shows a `wl18xx_driver_init()` is called, though that function again is not in the source code.

I can see the `wl18xx_driver_init()` in the objdump of `main.o` in that driver directory.

Is it that in late versions of kernels those functions/macros are automatically generated? How is that done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wl18xx_driver_init` is generated [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wl18xx/main.c#L2094) with the expansion of `module_platform_driver(wl18xx_driver)` macro.
It expands roughly to smth like:

```
static int __init wl18xx_driver_init(void) { 
   return platform_driver_register(&(wl18xx_driver)); 
} 
static initcall_t __initcall_wl18xx_driver_init6 __used __attribute__((__section__(".initcall" "6" ".init"))) = wl18xx_driver_init; 
static void __exit wl18xx_driver_exit(void) { 
    platform_driver_unregister(&(wl18xx_driver)); 
} 
static exitcall_t __exitcall_wl18xx_driver_exit __exit_call = wl18xx_driver_exit;
```

See [module_platform_driver macro](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/include/linux/platform_device.h#L227) and [module driver macro](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/include/linux/device.h#L1345).

@ It would be best to post some source code or links the next time, it would make it easier. Including kernel version would be also a good idea.